# how to keep always Rhistory file in home?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm so sorry for this question, but I cant find the way to solve my problem.

I want to save my .Rhistory always in a specific place, specifically in home directory (~/.Rhistory), even if a save my .RData in a different folder ( ~/Desktop/R_working_directory).

I'm using a macOS, in this sense if I going to close Rstudio, I have to change to home ( setwd("~/") ) and then close it to save my history in home, but some times I just forget to change to home directory, and then I have different .Rhistory files; I want to keep all the history in the same folder (something like shell/bash that always keep the history file in home: ~/.bash_history, even if the working directory is different !!).

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I think R will always save .Rhistory in your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitely save it with `savehistory(file = "mypath/wherever/today.Rhistory")`.

Comment: thanks, I was looking something for global option, I mean always keep the history in a single selected file !!! ... Thanks so much !!

Comment: You can probably do this. But it would require that you write your own package, make sure that Rstudio loads it on start-up and implement a hook in this package that loads your history from the desired location. Sounds like a lot of effort to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the `R_HISTFILE` environment variable to `~/.Rhistory` to make R look for it there to *restore* from it. You can do that by adding the following line to `~/.Renviron`[2], which contains user-defined environment variables:

```
   R_HISTFILE="~/.Rhistory"
```

2. Tell R to also *save* the history to this file on exit. For this, you can use the `.Last()` command, which "is (normally) executed at the very end of the session". This function should be defined inside `~/.Rprofile`[3], where your user-level configurations of R reside:

```
    .Last <- function() {
        if(interactive()) try(savehistory("~/.Rhistory"))
    }
```

Together, this should ensure that your history is stored in as well as restored from one single file. See [this chapter in R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Customizing-the-environment) for more information.

Keep in mind, however, that should you create `.Renviron` and/or `.Rprofile` in your project folder, these will override your user-level settings. To prevent that, import your user-level settings into your project explicitly by adding the following lines into your project's `.Rprofile`:

```
    readEnviron("~/.Renviron") # adds your user-level `.Renviron`
    source("~/.Rprofile")      # adds your user-level `.Rprofile`
```

See `help("Startup")` in R for more information.

---

[2]: This file's location can actually be controlled by using another environment variable, `R_ENVIRON_USER`

[3]: dito, but with `R_PROFILE_USER`

---

Edit: In Step 2, added the check for an interactive session (basically, whether R was opened by you or as part of some script) as recommended by R - see `help("savehistory")`